# How to get the Namescope of a control in UWP/Windows 8.1

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-8.1

WPF has a method called NameScope.GetNameScope(control). How can you get the same thing in UWP/Windows 8.1? The runtime must be doing it internally somehow or else ElementName bindings wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

[XAML namescopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namescopes) do exist in UWP, but currently there's no public API similar to WPF's GetNameScope(control).

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you will most likely have to fall back on using [FindName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_FindName_System_String_) or [GetTemplateChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_GetTemplateChild_System_String_) methods or ultimatly the [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper).

> Because of the separate XAML namescopes, finding named elements within
>   a template from the scope of the page where the template is applied
>   requires a different technique. Rather than calling FindName on some
>   object in the object tree, you first obtain the object that has the
>   template applied, and then call GetTemplateChild.